# Modifiers of elements inside segmented picker don't work

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a code:

```
@Binding var hand: Hand

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text("Hand: ")
        Picker(selection: $hand, label: Text("Strength")) {
            Text("JIUJIU").tag(0).foregroundColor(.blue)
            Text("BLABLA").tag(1).rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 35))
        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
    }
}
```

There is `foregroundColor(.blue)` and `rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 35))` modifiers inside elements of `Picker`. But in fact I see nor any effect:

[image]

Why modifiers don't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is your `pickerStyle()`. The documentation says concerning the `SegmentedPickerStyle`:

> - Note: Only supports segments of type `Label` and `Image`. Passing any
>     other type of view will result in a visible, but empty, segment.

I think that is why you only see the text. I have tried using another style and that worked fine.